# how can i implement django input form with the default values

Tags: python, django, django-forms

writing an online store
I have a form to add items to cart with different quantities.
I have implemented this through "TypedChoiceField":

```
class CartAddProductRetailForm(forms.Form):

    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=PRODUCT_RETAIL_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
        coerce=int,
        label='quantity',
    )
```

[image]

But it looks ridiculous.

Can you tell me how to implement it with a "CharField" or "DecimalField" with a default '1' value.

```
quantity = forms.DecimalField(max_value=999, min_value=1, )
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the value is supposed to be an integer, use an IntegerField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Form.initial` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values)).

```
#when instantiating your form
quantity = forms.DecimalField(max_value=999, min_value=1, initial={'quantity':1})
```

or

```
#when defining your form
class CartAddProductRetailForm(forms.Form):

    quantity = forms.DecimalField(
        choices=PRODUCT_RETAIL_QUANTITY_CHOICES,
        coerce=int,
        label='quantity',
        initial=1,
    )
```